# On $X_1\cup X_2$ define a well-ordered set preserving the order relations defined set on $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, well-orders

I am a bit of a newbie in math and I am struggling with the question written below.

> **Question:** Let $(X_1,\leq_{X_1}),(X_2,\leq_{X_2})$ to be a well-ordered set, and $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$
>
> On $X_1\cup X_2$, define a well-ordered set preserving the order relations defined set on $X_1$ and $X_2$ sets.

I am not very familiar with the notion of "well-ordered set", I have read it but I do not seem to grasp what role it would play to answer the question. Can you give me some insights on how to use it and on what does it mean to preserve teh property for the union? What properties does the realtion between an element of $X_1$ and $X_2$ should have? Am I allowed to arbitrary sort elements of $X_1$ with respect to those of $X_2$ as I wish as far as I preserve the order for the elements within the original sets?

**Update on the answer:**
Thanks to the comments and answer I understood that the question was rather trivial. Indeed having the freedom to define the relation we can simply do as follows: preserve the relation we have within the sets $X_1$ and $X_2$, and define a suitable behaviour for the remaining case. A simple example would be to use the set name to order elements of different sets in an arbitrary way. This is feasible since we have an empty intersection. Specifically, a solution would be to define $\leq_{X_1\cup X_2}$ on $X_1\cup X_2$ as follows, which also generalize to more disjuncted sets:

\begin{equation}
u \leq_{X_1\cup X_2} v =  
\begin{cases}
      u \leq_{X_i} v & \text{if}\ u\in X_i \wedge v \in X_i \\
      i \lt j & \text{if}\ u\in X_i \wedge v \in X_j \wedge i \neq j
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you know what a well-ordering is?

Comment: I have learnt about it a bit, after seeing this quesiton. But I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Here you really don’t need to use them. You need to define a well order on $X_1\cup X_2$ whose restrictions to $X_1$ and to $X_2$ agree with the original orders $\le_{X_1}$ and $\le_{X_2}$, respectively. HINT: Try putting one of the orders after the other.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I am struggling to understand because I am not into math terms, especially with the long ones.

Comment: You don’t even have to know what a well order is in order to get started. You have two linearly ordered sets, $X_1$ and $X_2$. You can combine them into a single linearly ordered set in many ways, but one very simple one is to leave each of them ordered just as it is and say that everything in $X_1$ precedes everything in $X_2$. That defines a linear order on $X_1\cup X_2$, and you need only verify that every non-empty subset of $X_1\cup X_2$ has a least element in that order.

Comment: I've been trying to solve it but I am unable to show X1's and X2's elements. Before combining them, because they are "ordered set" I need to show their elements or an expression. Don't I need elements to combine 2 sets? How can I do that?

Comment: No, you don’t. You just need to say how any two elements of $X_1\cup X_2$ are ordered by the order relation that you’re defining, which I’ll call $\le$. You want $\le$ to agree with $\le_{X_1}$ on $X_1$, so you define it that way: for any $x,y\in X_1$, $x\le y$ if and only if $x\le_{X_1}y$. You need to do something similar for $x,y\in X_2$. That leaves the case in which $x\in X_1$ and $y\in X_2$, and in my previous comment I described informally one easy thing to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113008/discussion-between-colleg-an-delta-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott
What if we choose sets of X1 and X2, which has "partial ordered relation" and "well-ordered set" properties?
And show "$X1\cup X2$ is a well-ordered set"?

Would it work?

Comment: What do you mean by a partial order that has well-ordered set properties?

Comment: Like:

$$X_1=\{(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0)\}$$

$$X_2=\{(1,1),(1,3),(3,3),(3,1)\}$$
they are both reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric.
$$X_1\cup X_2=\{(0,0),(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(1,1),(1,3),(3,3),(3,1)\}$$

Comment: I’m sorry, but I really don’t understand what you’re getting at, or what this has to do with the original question.

Comment: Okay, you're right. After several hours of struggling, I think I'm kinda lost. Maybe I should check it out later.

But at the end of the end, you said we need to verify "that every non-empty subset of X1∪X2 has a least element in that order."

How can I verify it without having elements?

Comment: I did something. I hope it is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well-ordered set $(X,\leq_X)$ is a set $X$ equipped with a relation $\leq_X$ such that:
$$1. \forall x\in X,\, x\leq_Xx\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Reflexive)}\\
  2. \forall x,y\in X, \, x\leq_Xy\,\, \text{and} \,\, y\leq_Xx\Rightarrow y=x\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Antisymmetric)}\\
  3. \forall x,y,z\in X, \, x\leq_Xy\,\, \text{and} \,\, y\leq_Xz\Rightarrow x\leq_Xz\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Transitive)}\\
  4. \forall x,y\in X, \text{   either  }x\leq_Xy\text{   or    } y\leq_Xx\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Connex)} $$
Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are disjoint in your problem, can you think of an order $\leq_{X_1\cup X_2}$ which makes $(X,\leq_{X_1\cup X_2})$ into a well-ordered set? (Hint: try "putting $X_2$ after $X_1$")

You might want to look into partial orders, and ordinals.